# Manual Histogram plot in python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I'm using matplotlib to make a histogram.

Basically, I'm wondering if there is any way to manually set the bins as well as the their values and still get the result as if the graph is made my matplotlin histogram. Below are my bins and their corresponding value.

```
0-7     0.9375
7-13    0.9490740741
13-18   0.8285714286 
18-28   0.880952381
28-37   0.92164903
37-48   0.9345357019
48-112  0.9400368773
```

This is the bar code i have implemented

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(maxlist, mean)
plt.show()

maxlist = [7.0, 13.0, 18.0, 28.0, 37.0, 48.0, 112.0]
mean = [0.9375, 0.94907407407777766, 0.82857142858571442, 0.88095238094999995, 0.92164902996666676, 0.93453570191250002, 0.94003687729000018]
```

This is what the bar plot of the above code looks like.
[image: histwithoutwidth]

I also tried playing with width parameter but the bar seems to overlap in that case, which doesn't happen in histogram.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(maxlist, mean,width = 6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

What i want is the bar plot to look like histogram as shown below, without any overlaps. Anyone with any ideas how to do this in python /ipython notebook. [image]

Comment: so you want the bars to be equal width, but the base of them not equal width? or do you some of the bars to be wider to fill in the gaps?

Comment: Bins allow you to give very specific bins, by passing a list. The display is not affected. For that look to  `histtype` , `align` and `rwidth` in the excellent documentation: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html.

Comment: @maxymoo I want bars of equal length, without having them to overlap with each other. Base cannot be of equal length since the range of bin differ everytime. Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation linked by @roadrunner66,

> `matplotlib.pyplot.bar(left, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, hold=None, data=None, **kwargs)`
>
> Make a bar plot with rectangles bounded by:
>
> `left`, `left + width`, `bottom`, `bottom + height`
>
> (left, right, bottom and top edges)

The first parameter passed to `bar` is actually the left edge of your "bin." It seems that `maxlist`, which you're passing as `left` is actually the right edge of your bins which is throwing everything off and causing your widths to be weird.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x1 = [0, 7, 13, 18, 28, 37, 48] #left edge
x2 = x1[1::] + [112] #right edge
y = [0.9375, 0.94907407407777766, 0.82857142858571442, 0.88095238094999995, 0.92164902996666676, 0.93453570191250002, 0.94003687729000018]
w = np.array(x2) - np.array(x1) #variable width, can set this as a scalar also
plt.bar(x1, y, width=w, align='edge')
plt.show()
```

[image: Bar chart with variable bin widths]

The bar widths are representative of the distances between the left and right edges, `x1` and `x2`. If you wanted constant widths, just pass `width=w_scalar` to `plt.bar()`, where `w_scalar` is your constant bin width. If you want the bars farther apart, just make `width` smaller.